# Google Finance US dollar index

Tags: stocks, chart, google-finance, quotes, google

Why Google Finance does not process a quote for "dxy" - u.s. dollar index?

what are prefix standards to specify various  indexes, mutual fund and stocks
traded on foreign exchanges?

Thanks.